# Rails 3.o MYSQL connection problem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have installed RVM in my ubunut linux box and configured the Rails 3 app in that ... i can able to start app server... my problem is when i invoke http://localhost:3000 . i getting the follwing error

```
Mysql::Error (Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)):
```

I checked mysqld service is running well.

I checked my database.yml file .... the defined well

```
development:
 adapter: mysql
 encoding: utf8
 reconnect: false
 database: test_development
 username: root
 password: admin
 socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

my installed mysql gem version is 2.8.1.... I really don't know what is the problem here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mysql server might be started, it seems the socket leading to it isn't available at the path you're providing to it (`/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`).

You must change this socket path to the appropriate one in your machine.
The best way to find it is the following in a console : `sudo find / -name mysqld.sock`
Then you'll get the path and you'll just have to change it in your configuration file.